# Answers that clearly miss an important mark: Addressing the issue at the asker's level

Tags: discussion

I was perusing some questions that were interesting to me, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362924/why-do-we-parameterize-our-solutions-equations?rq=1).

A sadly overlooked question, but with one very good answer*. The asterisk being that it completely barrages the asker with information that seems like it's probably way above their level of understanding as of yet.

Obviously, I'm making some assumptions here, but the question and answer look to me like the asker felt like accepting the answer was the right thing to do, but really didn't even know enough to find a good follow-up question.

I've seen this on quite a few occasions, and I always wonder whether I should vote.

Perhaps a bit cynically, I think, well I definitely don't want to downvote, because it's a good answer. But I don't want to upvote either, because the answer completely failed to provide any useful knowledge to the asker themselves. So I generally just leave it alone.

Does anyone else see this from time to time? I know there's no definitive "here's what you do" for this situation, but mindsets can be shared too.

Comment: I suppose you could find some older discussions about this (or at least related). For example, [Matching level of answer to level of question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25866) or [Is it OK to answer a question with a higher level of mathematics than I expect the OP to know?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11419) (Maybe also: [Answers that do not help but take away attention](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22745).)

Comment: I think you're right. I threw myself the first close vote. Somehow, they eluded me in the search, but they showed up in the "Related" column after I had posted.